# Power BI combine and with or filter

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, m

I need to filter a table. Maybe with a Formula which would look kind of like this:

```
Filter = IF ( table[column] contains ("A" && "B") || ("A" && "C"), table[column] )
```

or maybe like this:

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom",
      each Text.Contains([column], "A" and "B") or Text.Contains([column], "A" and "C")
  )
```

But none of these work.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your M code isn't too far off. Try this after the `each`:

```
( Text.Contains([column], "A") and Text.Contains([column], "B") ) or
( Text.Contains([column], "A") and Text.Contains([column], "C") )
```